# Prove that $\{f(x_n)\} $ converges to the constant point of the function $f$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Definition :

A function $f:[a,b] \to [a,b]$ is contractile on $[a,b]$ , if there exists a constant number $\alpha \in (0,1)$ such that for each $x,y \in [a,b]$, We have :
 $|f(y)-f(x)| \le \alpha|y-x|$

Question :

Assume that $f$ is a contractile function on $[a,b]$ .  Let $x_0$ denote an arbitrary point on $[a,b]$ and define a recursive sequence $\{x_n\}$ this way :

For each natural number $n$ , $x_n=f(x_{n-1})$.
Prove that $\{f(x_n)\} $ converges to the constant point of the function $f$.

Note 1 : This question is a part of a bigger question. In the previous parts, we've shown that $f$ has a unique constant point on $[a,b]$. I mean, there is a point such that $f(x)=x$.

Note 2 : My problem is that i don't know the relation between the constant point of $f$ and convergence of $\{f(x_n)\}$! Why should $\{f(x_n)\}$ converge to that point ? i don't have a clear image of this question... that's why i'm stuck ...

Comment: Have you tried invoking the fact that the interval is a compact?

Comment: @JohnMayne, I guess completeness of $[a, b]$ is sufficient. The crux is that $(x_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is Cauchy.

Comment: Assuming that $(x_n)$ converges to some $\ell$, taking the limit to the recurrence relation gives $\ell = f(\ell)$. That is, constant points (or fixed points, depending on the literature) are the only possible candidates of the limit of $(x_n)$.

Comment: @JohnMayne i don't know anything about compactness ... please don't use that

Comment: Let $y$ be the fixed point of $f$. Look at the sequence $d_n = \lvert y - x_n\rvert$, and think of the contractiveness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\{x_{n}\}\to x \in [a,b]$ then $\{x_{n+1}\}=\{f(x_{n})\}\to x$ but $f$ is continue, so $\{f(x_{n})\} \to f(x)$ so $f(x)=x$.